# Authorization errors using Azure Information Protection

Tags: azure, azure-information-protection

Getting the following message.

Experiencing authentication issues
The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.

Additional information from the call to get a token:
Extension: Microsoft_Azure_InformationProtection
Resource: self
Details: AADSTS500014: The service principal for resource 'https://api.aadrm.com/' is disabled.  This indicate that a subscription within the tenant has lapsed, or that the administrator for this tenant has disabled the application, preventing tokens from being issued for it.
Trace ID: cb750235-937e-426c-bfa9-48e42e632300
Correlation ID: 3b06392a-3ded-4b06-8183-96db22c9cf55
Timestamp: 2020-09-07 13:12:15Z

Answer (score 0):

If the subscription has not lapsed then an admin must have disabled it. If you have an admin account you can re-enable it trough the Azure Portal toggling *Enabled for users to sign-in?* to *Yes*:

[image]